# pushing packaged task into container causes C2280 error in VS2013

Tags: c++, concurrent.futures

I want to use packaged_tasks to add tasks to a container. I create a task, bind it to a number and try to push it into my deque. I get compiler error C2280 (VS2013) on the push_back. Here is the code:

```
void DoTask( int i )
{
  std::cout << "int value: " << i << std::endl;
}

std::deque< std::packaged_task< void() > > task_q;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  std::packaged_task< void() > t( std::bind( DoTask, 3 ) );
  task_q.push_back( t ); // <-- C2280 error

  return 0;
}
```

I got this sample code from a YouTube Bo Qian lecture called "C++ Threading #9: packaged_task".
Here is some error code text:

```
error C2280: 
    'std::packaged_task<void (void)>::packaged_task(const std::packaged_task<void (void)> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function... see declaration of 'std::packaged_task<void (void)>::packaged_task'...while compiling class template member function 'void std::allocator<_Ty>::construct(_Ty *,const _Ty &)'
    1>          with
    1>          [
    1>              _Ty=std::packaged_task<void (void)>"
```

Here is the code after two corrections (move task and non-void return value):

```
int DoTask( int i ) // non-void return value
{
  return i;
}

std::deque< std::packaged_task< int() > > task_q; // bind eliminates need for arg (Bo Qian lecture)

int _tmain( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] )
{
  std::packaged_task< int() > t( std::bind( DoTask, 3 ) ); // bind eliminates need for arg
  task_q.push_back( std::move( t ) ); // <-- move not copy

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the text of the error instead of just the error number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Copy constructor of `packaged_task` is deleted. Use:

```
task_q.push_back( std::move(t) );
```

Comment: So, are you saying that the error message should or could read 'attempting to reference a deleted function' where function is the 'copy constructor'? Where/how does t's copy ctor get deleted?

Comment: @rtischer8277, Yes. The [documentation of `std::packaged_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task/packaged_task) shows that the copy constructor is deleted.

Comment: the link to the documentation explaining there was no copy ctor helped my understanding considerably. There is, however, another problem. The code still does not compile unless I return a value instead of void. I figured this out using trial n error, but is this documented in the reference material somewhere?

Comment: @rtischer8277, glad I was able to help you.

Comment: Maybe the whole idea of a packaged_task is to return a future and it doesn't make sense not to return a value. At any rate, just not asking for a future, but still returning a value seems to work. A better compiler error other than C2182 (: '_Get_value' : illegal use of type 'void') would be helpful for the unsuspecting.